# replace a div tag using JQuery after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am submitting a form without leaving my page through a post call Using JQuery.

After I submit I want to replace the div with the form in it with a thank you message.  The problem is the message is showing before I submit and not replacing, below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //When the form with id="myform" is submitted...
            $("#myform").submit(function() {
                //Send the serialized data to mailer.php.
                $.post("mailer.php", $("#myform").serialize(),
                    //Take our repsonse, and replace whatever is in the "formResponse"
                    //div with it.
                    function(data) {
                        $("#formResponse").html(data);
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
```

**and the HTML**

```
<div data-role="content">
<form id="myform">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="company">Company Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value=""  />
</div>        
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" data-icon="star" data-theme="b" />
</form>

</div>
<div data-role="content" div id="formResponse">
    thank you, your quote has been received and you will hear back from us shortly.
    </div>
```

Comment: @Dan - I think this makes sense... *"After I submit I want to replace the div with the form in it with a thank you message."*

Comment: please improve your acceptance level

Comment: I will accept in a minute I like Nelsons answer and am working through it, still having a small issue, but almost got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your following code:

```
<div data-role="content" div id="formResponse">
```

for this one:

```
<div data-role="content" style="display:none" id="formResponse">
```

and then replace your following javascript function:

```
function(data) {
  $("#formResponse").html(data);
}
```

for this one:

```
function(data) {
  $("#myForm").html( $("#formResponse").html() );
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you just want to show the result obtained from the ajax call, instead of showing the content of the `#formResponse` div, just remove the `#formResponse` div at all, and just do the following:

```
function(data) {
  $("#myForm").html( data );
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
You can also hide the form div and show the "thank you" div, like this:

```
function(data) {
  $("#myForm").hide('slide', function() {$("#formResponse").show('slide');});
}
```

Comment: That makes sense and hid the div, however it didnt replace it with form response?  Do I need to name the div my form is in id="myform"?

Comment: If you just want to show the text returned from ajax call, you can go without the #formResponse div, so remove it and just directly replace your submit form content with the content returned by your ajax call. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear there.  I want to show the content of #formResponse div, but when I ran this and clicked submit nothing happened.  The form submitted fine, but it just stayed on the page instead of being replaced by my thank you message in #formResponse and I was wondering if it was because it wasn't sure what to replace?  So your first answer was great, but something didn't work correctly

Comment: Look at your javascript console for some error that could be stopping execution, also I've updated my answer with an alternative way.

Comment: Both ways I get an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Ok what I thought, you have javascript error stopping execution, try pasting all you javascript code to http://pastie.org and paste link here so I can try help you find the offending line.. Try to see if it says what line the error is..

Comment: http://pastie.org/5043965 This is my custom .js file, I also have a JQuery Mobile and Phonegap library attached.  Thank you soo much!

Comment: See my pastie -> http://pastie.org/5044047  it seems you are confusing php syntax with javascript syntax, you should only use dollar sign on jquery calls, not the ones you have in the previous pastie.

Comment: Not too sure, I copied the code to pull in a video stream from a youtube channel, its a little over my head.  It works alone fine though its just the new javascript that is having an issue?  any suggestions?

Comment: I got it to work it was a silly typo, I had the myForm instead of myform, lol.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

use `success(data)` A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.